# installing phpmyadmin via docker-compose

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, drupal-7

I set up my `docker-compose.yml` for Drupal 7. It all works. No i wanted to install phpMyAdmin and i cant get it to work.

I added some additional lines in the `docker-compose.yml` like adding `depends_on` or `links`. I first tinkered with installing it outside of docker but that was pointless.

Here is my `docker-compose-yml`.

```
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.2
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: <paswd>
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: <pswd>
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - drupal
  drupal:
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
       - ./app:/app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - drupal
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
        - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
        - db
    ports:
        - "8000:80"
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: db
    restart: always
networks:
   drupal:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

When i enter 'ip-address-of-my-server' into my addressbar i get to my drupal site. But when i enter 'ip-address-of-my-server'/phpmyadmin i only get the error, that the site does not exist, instead of visiting the phpmyadmin login page.

Edit (my apache-drupal.conf):

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin/
<Directory /var/www/phpmyadmin/>
   AllowOverride all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /app/web

        <Directory /app/web>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Do you have a route in your application that proxies to phpmyadmin, so that URL would work?  Or do you mean something like `http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin` to reach the other container?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Yes, something like http://localhost/phpmyadmin or similar would be great. I tried editing my apache-drupal.conf (see edit of my question) but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You would require a proxy or altering to your drupal apache config for the subfolder `phpmyadmin` to work on port 80.

I would suggest trying

`http://{server}:8000/` or `http://{server}:8000/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my apache-drupal.conf (see edit of my question) but i think i got it wrong since it is not working. Du you have a suggtestion how i have to rewrite the .conf-file?

Comment: I would configure it as a proxy. Your current config is more like a subdomain / additional directory.

Since the content lives on another container do something like this:

`ProxyPass "/phpmyadmin/"  "http://phpmyadmin:8000/phpmyadmin/"`

Not forgetting the proxy reverse also:
`ProxyPassReverse    /phpmyadmin/     http://phpmyadmin:8000/phpmyadmin/`

You would also need to update your docker-compose file to add a link between the drupal container and the phpmyadmin one. 

`links:
        - phpmyadmin`